# how to use mockito and junit to test my spring boot rest api?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I'm new in unit testing and cannot figure out how to  test the RESTFul API with Spring using Mockito and Junit, first of all i have preapared the class in which i created two method with **@Before** and **@Test**, when i turned in debugging mode it tells me that hasSize collection return 0 not 4.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class EmployeControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeController employeController ; 
    @Mock
    private EmployeService employeService ;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeController).build();
    }
    @Test
    public void testgetAllEmployee() throws Exception{
        List<Employe> employes= Arrays.asList(
                new Employe("Hamza", "Khadhri", "hamza1007", "123")
                ,new Employe("Oussema", "smi", "oussama", "1234") );
        when(employeService.findAll()).thenReturn(employes);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/employe/dto"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(4)))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].nom", is("Hamza")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].prenom", is("Khadhri")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].login", is("hamza1007")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].mp", is("123")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].nom", is("Oussema")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].prenom", is("smi")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].login", is("oussama")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].mp", is("1234")));

        verify(employeService,times(1)).findAll();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(employeService);
    }
}
```

here is the EmployeController :

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/employe")
    public class EmployeController {
        @Autowired
        private EmployeService employeService;

        @Autowired
        private ModelMapper modelMapper;

        @GetMapping("/dto")
        public List<EmployeDTO> getEmployeDTOList(){
            try {
                    List<Employe> listemp=employeService.findAllEmployeActive();
                    return listemp.stream()
                        .map(emp ->convertToDto(emp))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        private EmployeDTO convertToDto(Employe emp) {
            EmployeDTO empDto = modelMapper.map(emp, EmployeDTO.class);

            return empDto;
       }
   }
```

when I turn in debugging mode, it tells me that there is `NullPointerException`.

How to use properly `mockito` and `junit` to succeed the test?

Comment: Your controller calls `convertToDto()` which is dependent on `modelMapper.map()` from `ModelMapper`. You need to mock that service call as well

Comment: it's inside the controller ? how to do it ?

Comment: I'll see if I can write up an example later today. You basically need to mock the modelMapper, and have Mockito return dummy data whenever (use `Mockito.when()`) it is called rather than whatever the method would normally return.

Comment: i think that my problem is related to json jayway syntax exactly jsonPath ($,hasSize(2)) , $ he can't define the object based on $.

Comment: Well that's easy enough to determine: does the operation still "work" if you instead return the list of Employees directly instead of mapping them to DTO objects? If not, then you may be on the right track. Otherwise, I suspect it is what I already mentioned and you need to handle the `modelMapper` service dependency

Comment: Or you could create a spy and call the actual service, which works fine if you can assume that it always will work.

Comment: Another issue I see is that you have `employeService.findAllEmployeActive()` called in your controller but `when(employeService.findAll())` in your test. Not sure if that's intentional or not but could be part of your issue.

Comment: [see here](https://github.com/xerx593/soq54538520) (working spring-boot mvc test example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few potential issues:

First, you are calling

```
List<Employe> listemp=employeService.findAllEmployeActive();
```

in your controller's `getEmployeDTOList()`, but your Mockito mock is written as:

```
when(employeService.findAll()).thenReturn(employes)
```

So, your test might not be working simply because your mock never happens.

Second, you have not mocked the `ModelMapper` that you autowired in your controller. I *think* Spring will still go ahead and grab that component for you (someone correct me if I'm wrong there), but either way it's not great practice to have your unit tests be dependent on external libraries since you should only be concerned with the controller's functionality. It would be better to mock `ModelMapper` to make it "always" work and write separate tests to validate your mappings.

I went ahead and made my own version of your code to test things out. I changed `hasSize` to 2 because you were only using two elements in your example.

This test is working for me:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class EmployeeControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeController employeeController ; 
    @Mock
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @Mock
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeeController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testgetAllEmployeeWithModelMapper() throws Exception{
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Hamza", "Khadhri", "hamza1007", "123");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Oussema", "smi", "oussama", "1234");
        List<Employee> Employees= Arrays.asList(emp1, emp2);

        EmployeeDTO dto1 = new EmployeeDTO("Hamza", "Khadhri", "hamza1007", "123");
        EmployeeDTO dto2 = new EmployeeDTO("Oussema", "smi", "oussama", "1234");
        when(modelMapper.map(emp1,EmployeeDTO.class)).thenReturn(dto1);
        when(modelMapper.map(emp2,EmployeeDTO.class)).thenReturn(dto2);

        when(employeeService.findAll()).thenReturn(Employees);


        mockMvc.perform(get("/employe/dto"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].nom", is("Hamza")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].prenom", is("Khadhri")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].login", is("hamza1007")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].mp", is("123")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].nom", is("Oussema")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].prenom", is("smi")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].login", is("oussama")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].mp", is("1234")));

        verify(employeeService,times(1)).findAll();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(employeeService);

    }

}
```

As you can see I create my own DTO objects and pass them back so that `modelMapper` will always behave as expected for this unit test.

Comment: i understand ! I have integrated your method and it works ! But, when i'm in **jsonPath("$[0].nom", is("Hamza")**, the console tolds me that  **expected Oussema** not ** Hamza** !!! the index 0 it works for the second object **emp2**, and i think that is not correct somehow !!

Comment: Well I made some assumptions about how your Employee objects are converted to EmployeeDTO objects. Is the ordering of the objects guaranteed to be preserved? Because it sounds like they are in a different order after being mapped.

Comment: I did like you, the same order  i even add two contructor , in Employe and EmployeDTO.

Comment: Well that's odd...not sure why that would be happening

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works but it ignores the object **emp1**:

```
 public void testgetAllEmployeeWithModelMapper() throws Exception{
         Employe emp1 = new Employe("Hamza", "Khadhri", "hamza1007", "123");
         Employe emp2 = new Employe("Oussem", "smi", "oussama", "1234");
         List<Employe> Employees= Arrays.asList(emp1, emp2);
         EmployeDTO dto1 = new EmployeDTO("Hamza", "Khadhri", "hamza1007", "123");
         EmployeDTO dto2 = new EmployeDTO("Oussem", "smi", "oussama", "1234");
         when(modelMapper.map(emp1,EmployeDTO.class)).thenReturn(dto1);
         when(modelMapper.map(emp2,EmployeDTO.class)).thenReturn(dto2);

         when(employeeService.findAll()).thenReturn(Employees);
         mockMvc.perform(get("/employe/dto"))
         .andExpect(status().isOk())
         .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].nom", is("Hamza")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].prenom", is("Khadhri")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].login", is("Hamza1007")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].mp", is("123")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].nom", is("Oussema")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].prenom", is("smi")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].login", is("oussama")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].mp", is("1234")));

     verify(employeeService,times(1)).findAll();
     verifyNoMoreInteractions(employeeService);
    }

}
```

The cosole shows me that **jsonPath("$[0].nom"** expect **Oussema**
so when i change it to Oussema which is the object **emp2** and it works well. unfortunately it ignores the the object **emp1** which contain **Hamza**,
personnaly i just add two constructor in Employe and EmployeDTO.

this is the class Employe:

```
 public class Employe implements Serializable {



    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, precision=6)
    private Long id;
    @Column(precision=6)
    private BigDecimal cv;
    @Column(length=254)
    private String nom;
    @Column(length=254)
    private String prenom;
    @Column(length=254)
    private String login;
    @Column(length=254)
    private String mp;
    @Column(length=254)
    private String mail;
    @Column(precision=6)
    private BigDecimal idpointage;
    @Column(length=1)
    private Boolean actif;
    public Employe(String nom, String prenom, String login, String mp) {

        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.login = login;
        this.mp = mp;
    }
```

this is the class EmployeDTO:

```
public class EmployeDTO {
        private String nom;
        private String prenom;
        private String login ; 
        private String mp ; 


        public EmployeDTO(String nom, String prenom, String login, String mp) {

            this.nom= nom ; 
            this.prenom= prenom ; 
            this.login = login ; 
            this.mp=mp ;
        }
```